# Java Read Other Info In XML

Tags: java, xml

```
<list>
    <person>
        <nr>8</nr>
        <name>Andrew</name>
        <cash>1</cash>
    </person>
    <person>
        <nr>9</nr>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <cash>2</cash>
    </person>
</list>
```

Using this format for the XML, just wondering: 
Is it possible to search for the `name` to get the `nr`?
No need to edit or add info, simply want it to search for name and give me the nr.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath:

```
/*/person[name='Bob']/nr/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines :

```
public String getNR( File inputXml, String inputName )
{

      String nr = null;
      try
      {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse( new File( inputXml ) );
            XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile( "//list/person/name[text()=" + "'" + inputName + "'" + "]/parent::*/nr" );
            Object exprEval = expr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.NODESET );
            if ( exprEval != null && exprEval instanceof NodeList )
            {
                NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)exprEval;
                if ( nodeList.getLength() == 1 )
                {
                   nr =  nodeList.item(0).getTextContent();
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    return nr;
}
```

If you call `getNR( inputxml, "Bob")` it should return `9`.